# Ruby: How to dynamically replace parameters in native PG gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

As far as i have seen the documentation on some statements dynamic operations are not allowed like if i want to execute the statement

```
res = conn.exec_params('CREATE DATABASE $1',[dbname])
```

i am getting this error

```
Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE $1
```

while if i use select statement `SELECT * FROM pg_database WHERE datname = $1` this statement is successful.

While the above issue was not there with dbd/pg gem but it seems it hasnt been released from past 2010 which translate the dynamic paramters into native pg and with latest ruby and pg gem dbd/pg is not working.

My question is do we have any way with native PG gem to perform dynamic replacement of variables with create database, insert into like statements. OR is there any alternative for dbd/pg which offers same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, ...) are for values. A database name (or table name, column name, ...) is an identifier. This is similar to the difference between a variable name and the value the variable holds in Ruby.

If you need to dynamically insert an identifier in some SQL then you need to use string interpolation and the special purpose [`quote_ident`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PG%2FConnection%2Equote_ident) method to make sure you quote it properly. So something more like this:

```
db_name = conn.quote_ident(db_name)
res     = conn.exec("CREATE DATABASE #{db_name}")
```